# Rig Changing Poses By Itself

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I'm animating an action in blender using a rigify metarig, but it's acting weird. There are screenshots for each step so you can follow along and see clearly where things go wrong.

This is the first frame: [image: Step 1]

Ok, so far so good. Then, I move some bones and add another frame on frame 5:
[image: Step 2]

Still good so far. Then it starts breaking. Without changing anything, if I go back to the first frame, the left arm bones are in a new pose I never made, but the loc/rot values are still the same as before:
[image: Breaking]

If I move the left arm bones to a random position but don't overwrite the old keyframe:
[image: Random Position]

Then it arutomatically goes back to the pose it's supposed to be in:
[image: Fixed]

But then if I go back to frame 5, that one becomes broken instead!
[image: Wtf!?]

I've made tons of animations on other model's before using rigify metarigs and this is the first time I've ever seen this. It's super frustrating and I need this for a class assignment. Does anyone know what the hell is going on here?

Comment: Image 1 and 3 show the rotation values of the lower arm which appears to be correct. I would have been useful knowing the rotation values for the upper arm /shoulder, which changes as you pointed out.

Comment: You add a metarig, resize it to fit your model and then generate a rig, the original metarig is not needed after that. You appear to be animating the original armature, If you have generated a rig and also using the original metarig then you would have two armatures deforming your mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it. So, even though I was applying each keyframe with "whole character" I only ever had one bone selected while doing so. I tried doing the same thing with the entire rig selected and it didn't mess up. I'm not really sure what the correlation is between my issue and applying keyframes like that, or why I didn't need to do it that way for all my other animations, but what's fixed is fixed.